# Installation failed: had non-zero exit status

Tags: r, github, devtools, metafor, rtools

I am trying to install the development version of "metafor" package using

```
remotes::install_github("wviechtb/metafor")
```

However, I have the following error message. I tried setting dependencies and force to TRUE with no success.

.
.
.

```
*** copying figures
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
*** arch - i386
*** arch - x64
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386'
* removing 'C:/Users/mihir/OneDrive/Dokumente/R/win-library/4.0/metafor'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/mihir/OneDrive/Dokumente/R/win-library/4.0/metafor'
Error: Failed to install 'metafor' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/mihir/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpWcutv3/file121421b71d54/metafor_2.5-54.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status.

   

` sessionInfo()`

R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.3 tools_4.0.3
```

Comment: Have you successfully installed other github packages to this library location? Can you get access to any more detailed error messages? (One possible method would be to download the source code from the GitHub repo, via [this link](https://github.com/wviechtb/metafor/archive/master.zip), unpack it, and run `R CMD INSTALL` from the command line ...

Comment: ISTR that on some platforms that R is no longer distributed with i386 code. I do remember that for a while that Windows kept separate directories for that architecture.

Comment: Many thanks to both of you. It finally worked. I checked my .libpaths() and found two paths. I tried to install again and it failed because the path was not writable. Then, I closed R and open it as an administrator and then changed my path using .libPaths("C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.3/library"). Success!